# Is there a way in react to make the whole page not editable until a button click?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have my standard webpage and an overlay with a message and a checkbox. I want that you can not interact with the webpage until the checkbox in the overlay is clicked. Is there a way to do that in react?

Comment: You can wrap all the components you want in a container and then in the styles set user-select:none
When you want the components to be editable or clickable just remove the style from it.

Comment: Just make the overlay span the whole viewport and make it transparent.

Comment: yes, there multiple ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useState Hook` and set **disable** property in every field. After clicking on button you can set false to that property. Here is the example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const DisabledForm = () => {
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);

    function handleClick(event) {
        setDisable(!disable);
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <div>
                First Name: <input disabled={disable}/> <br/>
                Last Name: <input disabled={disable}/> <br/>
                Email: <input disabled={disable}/> <br/>
                Phone: <input disabled={disable}/> <br/>
                <button onClick={handleClick}>{ disable? "< Enable >" : "< Disable >" }</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default DisabledForm;
```